# Windows 7 being resumed with failure

Tags: windows

I have windows 7. I used to hibernate it, though it rarely resumes after that. It starts resuming and  stucks, then I turn off the laptop, start it again and choose continue resuming. Then the computer is up again. But sometimes some programs do not run properly.
Anyway, what is the problem?
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could have a few different problems. Hibernate is a more complex function than many people assume, because it requires both hardware and program support. First, use Windows Update to make sure you have the latest drivers for your system. To verify that all drivers are properly installed, go to the Start Menu and type "Device Manager" to open the Device Manager program. Ensure that no hardware in your system has a yellow or red icon indicating trouble of some kind.

Next, you should try enabling and disabling the hibernate function. Open the start menu, then type "cmd" and right-click on "cmd.exe" to open it with Administrator rights. Type `powercfg -h off` to disable hibernate. Restart your computer. Then, open your start menu, right click on your primary hard-drive (your primary drive has a small Windows icon next to it) and open the properties window. Click on "Disk Cleanup" and select the "Hibernation file cleaner" in order to delete the Hibernation File on your hard drive. After this has completed, reboot your computer again, then open the command prompt as discussed above. This time, type `powercfg -h on` to recreate the Hibernation File and enable the Hibernate feature on your machine once again. You may want to restart a third time just to be safe.

Finally, you may have a program running when your computer goes into Hibernate that is not compatible with the feature. If you continue to have trouble, you'll need to make sure all of your programs are Hibernate-compatible.